# How to install Bamboo plugin with add on key?

Tags: continuous-integration, bamboo

I am trying to configure Nunit test for our CI using Bamboo. So I installed 
Atlassian Bamboo .NET Plugin. The build works fine and is successfull, but tests were not being detected. SO when I checked the tasks, it was showing the build task is invalid with the error message

***re-install the plugin with key "com.atlassian.bamboo.plugin.dotnet:msbuild"***